Getting "Extra Data" error when trying to json.loads on two separate json strings
I have a program that involves sending python dicts that are converted into json using json.dumps back and forth to a server. I have one json response coming back from the server, which I then use json.loads on. When I try to do this for a second json response, I get this error: "raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 1455)"
I'm not sure how to fix this but I need to be able to access different variables inside both of the json strings/python dicts. Here's the relevant code:
First dictionary/string:
    firstDict = {"age": "20"}
    firstJson = json.dumps(firstDict) + '\n'
    s.sendall(bytes(firstJson, encoding = "utf-8"))
    jsonData += s.recv(8012).decode() + '\n'
    pyData = json.loads(jsonData)
    ageVar = pyData["age"]
    print(idVar)

Second:
     secDict = {"color": "red"}
     secJson = json.dumps(secDict) + '\n'
     s.sendall(bytes(secJson, encoding = "utf-8"))
     jsonAgain += s.recv(8012).decode() + '\n'
     pyAgain = json.loads(jsonAgain)
     colorVar = pyAgain["color"]
     print(marksVar)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!
I'm not really sure how to fix this, I've tried googling but I couldn't find anything relevant to my specific problem.

You should make an example that reproduces the error which would need both the client and server, but likely the problem is assuming TCP is message-based. It is not. Send the size of the json message before the message and check return values of send/recv to ensure you get a complete message.

Also, your jsonData += ... implies concatenation of two JSON together.  That would break the second time.  Since it isn't a example we can actually run, we can only guess.

Also see this answer for another method of sending multiple JSON through a socket.
